# Returning data one by one from action in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Is it possible to have one ajax call that will call action in MVC and the action will return data one by one.

Example:
We have large amount of images that need to be processed.
We have action in MVC that will processes the images.
On page load we will call that action and as images are processed we will return them one by one. Ajax call will received image one by one and will do something with them.

If it is possible please send me an example.

Comment: You will have to call the action multiple times, or  checkout something like Spring MVC etc. to use are push service

Comment: No - what you could do is to put the images somewhere on your server when they are processed. Then use SignalR to notify your client when each image is ready.